# Unable to get canvas toDataURL of content

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am unable to save this rounded image as png.

Here I am getting blank canvas as base code in console.

Anyone Please tell Me how can I save canvas content like rouneded image as an png or base 64 code.

```
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {

// Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
ctx.save();


// Create a circle
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(106, 77, 74, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

// Clip to the current path
ctx.clip();


ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// Undo the clipping
ctx.restore();
}

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";

var base = canvas.toDataURL();
console.log(base);
```

Comment: Is there an error in the console? Are you actually calling base line before the image loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait for the image to load before trying to use it.

On top of that you can't call `toDataURL` on *tainted* canvases. Tainted canvases are canvases that have had images drawn in them from other domains unless you both request permission to use the image AND the server gives you permission to use the image.

For your example imgur's servers usually give permission. To request permission you need to set `img.crossOrigin`.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

```js
// Grab the Canvas and Drawing Context
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');



// Create an image element
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

// When the image is loaded, draw it
img.onload = function () {

  // Save the state, so we can undo the clipping
  ctx.save();


  // Create a circle
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(106, 77, 74, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);

  // Clip to the current path
  ctx.clip();


  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // Undo the clipping
  ctx.restore();
  
  var base = canvas.toDataURL();
  console.log(base);
}

// Specify we want to ask the server for permission to use this image
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

// Specify the src to load the image
img.src = "http://i.imgur.com/gwlPu.jpg";
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: added an example